# Replace specific length sub-string in Java String

Tags: java, regex

I need to parse a string and mask all social security codes.  The SSNs are always exactly 9 digits.  For my purposes, if I see a 9 digit sub-string, I can assume it is a SSN or at least assume it is safe to mask.  However, I don't want to mask any numeric sub-strings that are less than or greater than 9 digits.

So, this code gets me close, but it finds 10 digit numeric strings and masks the first 9 of the digits.

```
String masked = myString.replaceAll( "\\d{9}", "XXXXXXXXX" );
```

- Input: `cat123456789dog`
- Output: `catXXXXXXXXXdog`
- Input: `cat1234567890dog`
- Output: `catXXXXXXXXX0dog`
- Desired Output: `cat1234567890dog`

Is there anyway to use the String `replaceAll` method, or perhaps another method to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use look arounds to ensure that its of lenght 9 as

```
(?<!\\d)\\d{9}(?!\\d)
```

[**Regex Example**](https://regex101.com/r/eG1jL4/1)

- `(?<!\\d)` negative look behind. Ensures that the digits of length `9` is not presceded by digits
- `(?!\\d)` negative look ahead. Ensures that the digits is not followed by digits as well
- The look arounds together restrict the total length of digits to 9

**OR**

Using caputre groups as

```
String masked = myString.replaceAll( "(\\D)\\d{9}(\\D)", "$1XXXXXXXXX$2" );
```